# Path cover in directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I cannot figure out what this theorem is trying to say:

> Every directed graph G has a path cover $\mathcal{P}$ and an
>   independent set $\{\mathcal{v}_P | P \in \mathcal{P}\}$ of vertices
>   such that $\mathcal{v}_P \in P$ for every $P\in\mathcal{P}$.

What is the second part of the theorem meant to express? It just seems cyclic to me. Also what is an independent set of vertices? Is it simply a set of independent vertices?

Source: http://www.flooved.com/reader/3447?no-redirect#67 (bottom of the page)

Comment: What it says is that on each of the paths of $\mathcal{P}$ you can pick a vertex so that the resulting vertices will be mutually non-adjacent.

Comment: So essentialy it should have been: $\{\mathcal{v}_p \in P | \forall P \in \mathcal{P}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Independent vertices do not have any edges joining them, that is, no two of them are adjacent.

The theorem says that you can partition the arcs of every directed graph into directed paths  $\mathcal P$ and for every such path $P \in \mathcal P$ you can find a special vertex $v_P$ (=representative) on $P$ which is not adjacent to any of the other representatives of all the other directed paths in $\mathcal P$.

A nice application to your theorem is the following: consider a tournament (a tournament is a directed graph obtained by assigning a direction for each edge in an undirected complete graph). Since any two distinct vertices in a tournament are adjacent, it follows that every tournament has a directed Hamilton path, that is, a directed path containing all vertices. Think about it.